# HTML ignore Line break <br> in text from Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I pass some text from `Flask_app` to `html`. I add a line break,  `<br>`, but it seems that it is ignored and all text gets printed on 1 line.

```py
@app.route('/description/')
def description():
    text = ['Line one <br> Line two']
    return render_template('Untitled-21.html', text=text)
```

HTML File:

```html
<h2 class="card-text"> {{ text }}</h2>
```

If I paste my text, as below, it works correctly:

```html
<h2 class="card-text"> {{ Line one <br> Line two }}</h2>
```

Why is this line break ignored?